# How do you return only groups that contain a specific value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table `mytable` with 2 columns like

```
|   foo   |  bar    | 
|   a     |   10    | 
|   b     |   10    |   
|   b     |   15    | 
|   c     |   10    | 
|   c     |   10    | 
|   c     |   10    |  
|   d     |   10    | 
|   d     |   45    |  
|   e     |   20    |
```

How I return the groups of `foo` that *only* contain the value `10`?

The resulting dataset for the above should look like

```
|   foo   |  bar    | 
|   a     |   10    |  
|   c     |   10    |
```

Note that b and d do not get returned because 15 and 45 are also values in those groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select foo
from mytable
group by foo
having min(bar) = max(bar) and min(bar) = 10;
```

if `10` is the minimum value:

```
having max(bar) = 10
```

Comment: Assume 10 is not the min value. Your suggestion of 

```having min(bar)=10 and max(bar)=10``` works though

Answer (score 0):

You could use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT foo
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.foo = t1.foo AND t2.bar <> 10);
```

This query should benefit from the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (foo, bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement, you need to tell the system to

1. retrieve the records where bar=10
2. filter out those which contains bar <> 10

The following are the suggested codes:

```
select foo, bar from mytable 
where 
bar=10 and foo not in (select foo from mytable where bar <> 10)
group by foo
```